# Maven Release Plugin For Multi-module projects - Updating dependency versions

Tags: maven, dependencies, multi-module

We have a multiple multi-module projects set up i.e:

```
>    Proj1
>      parent
>      mod1
>      mod2
>     Proj2
>      parent
>      mod1
>      mod2

...
```

Proj2 depends on Proj1. And so part of the pom.xml for Proj2 would be

```
>     <dependencies>
>     ....
>     <dependency>
>       <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
>       <artifactId>ABCXYZ</artifactId>
>       <version>${Proj1.version}</version>
>     </dependency>
>     </dependencies>
>     <properties>
>       <Proj1.version>1.0.0.RELEASE</Proj1.version>
>     </properties>
```

The question now is, is it possible using the maven release plugin for me to automate the release of this Proj2 such that the new release of Proj1 is picked up and replaced in the `<Proj1.version>` tags. When I tried the regular `mvn release:prepare-with-pom` I got a prompt for the dependencies update but when I entered the new version, it replaced it in the `<version>` tag which isn't desired.

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 2):

You may have a look to the [update-properties](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/examples/update-properties.html) goal of the [versions-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/).
I haven't use it for a while, it was working fine.

Your release workflow would be :

- Release `Proj1`
- Update `<Proj1.version>` of `Proj2` using versions-maven-plugin
- Commit `Proj2`
- Release `Proj2`

Comment: Thank you Gillaume. I had that thought in mind. It seemed a bit more cumbersome and risky I felt. I was hoping the maven release plugin had a way of doing this because it would seem like a common problem to be addressed.

Comment: Additionally, I realized even if I do this, the prepare-with-pom goal on the release plugin would still prompt me for the version to use for Proj1 and replace the `<version>` tag of the dependency thereby giving it a hard coded value. So the question still stands I guess whether we can use the above setup with the maven release plugin at all.

Comment: I don't know how is setup your `<scm>` tags, but if everything is properly configured, you don't have to use the `release:prepare-with-pom` goal at all. Just run `mvn -B release:prepare release:perform` to release a project (maybe with some options depending on your setup). `-B` is for batch mode which doesn't prompt for versions.